# AutoHotkey script triggered by Shift + g + AppsKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to trigger a script by pressing Shift + g + AppsKey at the same time.
I tried

```
AppsKey & +g::
```

and

```
AppsKey & + & g
```

but both don't seem to work.

```
AppsKey & g
```

works but doesn't require the shift key.
How do I include the shift key into the hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to make a three-key combination, which isn't supported by this short syntax. Making such a hotkey requires an additional if-statement.

You need to choose two keys that will enter the function, let's say <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, and then use [GetKeyState](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) for the third key. So, the solution is as follows:

```
AppsKey & G::
    If GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
        Send hello
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
#if GetKeyState("Shift")
~a & b::msgbox
#if
```

Comment: Sorry, but this script will cause regular shift-a presses to be ignored

Comment: you'll need the tilde `~` modifier in front of the `a`, then, as described @  http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro (see my post for updated code). thanks for the hint